# How do I portray therians in a way that's relatable and not weird?

Tags: characters

I'm writing a story on [therians](https://www.wikihow.com/What-Is-a-Therian), for therians themselves to enjoy and for people to understand them better, but it's turning out kind of weird. I was making this more for people  to stop hating therians, but it's ending up kind of weird and probably going to make them hate therians more.

I don't know what to do.

Comment: Therians being what exactly?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've added a link to clarify what therians are. (Basically, if anyone remembers the "On all levels except physical, I am a wolf" meme from several years ago, that's what a therian is. I've heard them referred to as "otherkin", but I wasn't familiar with the term "therian" until I looked it up just now.)

Comment: If you feel that you understand these people, you are better able to answer your own question than the majority of us who, far from 'hating therians',  have never even heard of the concept before.

Comment: Can you describe what in particular makes you believe that the story turned out weird and what in your story would trigger an increase in hatred? Also add a description of therians in the question, links are OK, but your definition is more valuable

Comment: There's stuff like making masks (animal masks) and quadrobix, which is running around on all fours lol. I don't know how to portray these things without it getting weird. But yall helped!

Answer (score 1):

Basically your questions boils down to how can you portray a mode of being that is alien to your audience in a way that it evokes sympathy and understanding instead of abhorrence. This is a problem that is commonplace in all aspects of everyday life and relates to all kinds of groups. For everyone, there are many kinds of people that they don't understand and potentially reject: citizens are wary of immigrants, whites are prejudiced against people of color, people of color are prejudiced against whites, men are misogynistic, women are misandric, heterosexuals have criminalized homosexuality, and so on and so forth.

The idea behind *social integration* is that those to whom a certain group of people is alien need to get to know that group, understand that they are "people like you and me" and become familiar with their way of life.

The problem with the integrative approach is that people are different: some people are [open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Openness_to_experience), tolerant and [seek novelty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novelty_seeking) by nature while others have a high need for security and the commonplace or are distrustful as an inherent part of their personality. An effect of this variability in human nature is that you can only sway a small percentage to a view they haven't held before. A large part of the population will be welcoming, another large part will be hostile, and you won't be able to change the attitudes of *both* groups by anything that you can do.

The latter group, the ones that are averse, by nature, to everyone who is different, will find therians *the more despicable, the more they learn about them*. It won't matter how you write about therianthropy, it will always disgust a large part of the population, just as some part of the people cannot be brought to embrace immigrants, homosexuals, blacks, whites and so on. It is not in their nature to like people who are unlike themselves.

But what can you do to sway those that can be swayed?

Simply put, what you need to do is show that part of your audience how similar the weird is to the normal when you look at it more closely. Therians love and want to be loved, they have dreams and fears like any other person, they try to be good people and fail like we all do, and so on. It doesn't so much matter if you think you are a dog or you think you are an English teacher – the basic principles of what it means to be human take effect in all of us.

The more you manage to show the fundamental *humanity* of therians, the more you can gain the sympathy of your audience.

But then that is the one basic writing skill that is necessary for all writing, isn't it? To portray characters that the readers can and want to identify with.

In practical terms:

- Develop a coherent backstory for your charcters: How did they become who they are?
- Give them goals, motivations, aspirations, and fears.
- Show what it means to be them, how they feel, how they struggle, how they fail and succeed.
- Make them complex, doubt themselves, experience support and opposition, difficulty and moments of happiness and peace.
- Show how they live their relationships, how they work, what their everyday life is like, and how *they* relate to those that aren't like them.